# Ruby on Rails through Heroku object associations :belongs_to :has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Real newb question here: I've got courses

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :name, :number

has_many :posts

validates :name, presence: true

validates :number, presence: true

validates :number, :format => { :with => /\A\d\d[-]?\d\d\d\z/}

end
```

and I've got posts

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :comments, :course_id, :difficulty, :enjoyability, :hours, :professor, :ranking, :semester, :usefulness

belongs_to :course

end
```

Almost everything I have was auto-generated by Rails. There are a couple of things I try to do that I can't get to work:

1. When I "show" a course, I want to show each post associated with that course. However, everything I've tried has given me an error.
2. After even entering one post into the database (heroku forced me to use PostgreSQL) the index form no longer renders.

I'm almost positive I'm missing something with my associations between them. Does anybody have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get all posts through Course instance:

```
@course = Course.find(params[:id])
@posts = @course.posts
```